# Export Panorama Equirectangular

Tags: export, panoramic

I'm new to blender and I'm trying to export an equirectangular panorama.
I've seen on youtube an option to choose Equirectangular after the panorama's choice.

But I can't find the equirectangular option in the camera tab. 
It simply isn't there. 
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Equirectangular option is only available when using the Cycles Rendering engine. If you are using the old "Blender Render", it will not be available.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I was using EEVEE for testing.